# Could not insert into temp table from WITH ROWS AS clause in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression

I want to insert a result that return by this query:

```
WITH rows AS 
                (
                SELECT  *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [発生時刻]) AS rn
                FROM    [PROC_MN].[dbo].[TBL_FINISH_STATUS]
                 where   PO_NO='GV12762' and 発生時刻 BETWEEN '2018/03/16' AND '2018/03/18' AND [加工内容]='Bonding'
                ) 
                SELECT  DATEDIFF(minute, mc.[発生時刻], mp.[発生時刻])
                FROM    rows mc
                JOIN    rows mp
                ON      mc.rn = mp.rn - 1
```

The resut is : 91

I use this query but cannot, please help!

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tempTest') IS NOT NULL     
    DROP TABLE #tempTest

        Insert into #tempTest
        WITH rows AS 
                (
                SELECT  *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [発生時刻]) AS rn
                FROM    [PROC_MN].[dbo].[TBL_FINISH_STATUS]
                 where   PO_NO='GV12762' and 発生時刻 BETWEEN '2018/03/16' AND '2018/03/18' AND [加工内容]='Bonding'
                ) 
                SELECT  DATEDIFF(minute, mc.[発生時刻], mp.[発生時刻])
                FROM    rows mc
                JOIN    rows mp
                ON      mc.rn = mp.rn - 1
```

EDITED: This one work for me

```
If(OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp') Is Not Null)
Begin
    Drop Table #Temp
End
create table #Temp
(
    OptTime int

)
;WITH rows AS 
                (
                SELECT  *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [発生時刻]) AS rn
                FROM    [PROC_MN].[dbo].[TBL_FINISH_STATUS]
                 where   PO_NO='GV12762' and 発生時刻 BETWEEN '2018/03/16' AND '2018/03/18' AND [加工内容]='Bonding'
                ) 

                INSERT INTO #Temp
                SELECT  DATEDIFF(minute, mc.[発生時刻], mp.[発生時刻])
                FROM    rows mc
                JOIN    rows mp
                ON      mc.rn = mp.rn - 1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong - if you want to insert from a CTE, do this:

```
; WITH rows AS 
(
    SELECT  
        *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [発生時刻]) AS rn
    FROM    
        [PROC_MN].[dbo].[TBL_FINISH_STATUS]
    WHERE
        PO_NO = 'GV12762' 
        AND 発生時刻 BETWEEN '2018/03/16' AND '2018/03/18' 
        AND [加工内容] = 'Bonding'
) 
INSERT INTO #tempTest
    SELECT (list of columns)
    FROM rows
    WHERE (conditions)
```

See [the official Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql) for details on the CTE syntax and how to use it

**Update:** if that target temp table doesn't exist yet - use this syntax:

```
; WITH rows AS 
(  .....    ) 
SELECT (list of columns)
INSERT INTO #tempTest
FROM rows
WHERE (conditions)
```

Comment: There is an inappropriate syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause, or a change tracking context clause, please terminate the previous statement with a semicolon.

Comment: @user3035133: as the error says - if you don't terminate the previous statement with a `;` (you should get into that habit by now!), then you need to have a `;` just before the `WITH` keyword

Comment: Invalid object name '# tempTest'.

Comment: Either create your #temptest table first or change the code to "INSERT (list of columns) INTO #tempTest  -- Come on!

Comment: @user3035133 Is there a blank between the `#` and the `tempTest`? No blanks here!

Answer (score 2):

Not only is the syntax wrong, but the logic is not very good either.  Just use `lag()`:

```
INSERT INTO #tempTest
    SELECT DATEDIFF(minute, LAG(fs.[発生時刻]) OVER (ORDER BY [発生時刻]), fs.[発生時刻])
    FROM [PROC_MN].[dbo].[TBL_FINISH_STATUS] fs
    WHERE PO_NO = 'GV12762' AND
          発生時刻 >= '2018-03-16' AND
          発生時刻 < '2018-03-18' AND
          [加工内容] = 'Bonding';
```

Notes:

- Use ISO/ANSI standard syntax for dates.  That is a hyphen rather than a slash.
- Don't use `BETWEEN` with dates, particularly if they have times.  You can refer to this [very helpful blog](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common) post by Aaron Bertrand.
- If you use the appropriate SQL functionality, your queries will be simpler.
- If you want to exclude `NULL`s you can use a subquery or CTE.

Comment: 'LAG' is not recognized as a built-in function name. I am using SQL Server 2008